# Proof exercise on the topic of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A and B be 2 x 2 real matrices:
A =$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}$,
B = $\begin{bmatrix}
x & y\\
z & t
\end{bmatrix}$.
And let be: $ A \otimes B = \begin{bmatrix}
ax & bx & ay & by\\
cx & dx & cy & dy\\
az & bz & at & bt\\
cz & dz & ct & dt
\end{bmatrix}$

Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for A and $\mu$ is an eigenvalue for B, then $\lambda \mu$ is an eigenvalue for $ A \otimes B$.

I'm not sure how to even begin with it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$  be the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ corresponding to the eigenvectors $\textbf v$ and $\textbf w$, respectively.

First note that $(\lambda \textbf v)\otimes \textbf w=\lambda (\textbf v\otimes\textbf w)= \textbf v\otimes(\lambda \textbf w)$ [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Properties)

We have $(A\otimes B)(\textbf v\otimes \textbf w)=A \textbf v\otimes B \textbf w=\lambda\textbf v\otimes \mu \textbf w=\lambda\mu (\textbf v\otimes \textbf w)$

Comment: Thank you! Is it here simultaneously proven that $(v \otimes w)$ is an eigenvector for $(A \otimes B)$?

Comment: The last line shows that. 
You can read more about the Kronecker Product here
https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789811202520_0002